# Server response TokenMismatch when use $resourse (angularjs) to PUT data after two days

Tags: angularjs, ajax, refresh, token

I have a problem when building the website to upload data to server. When user logs in and changes data, I use $resource (AngularJS) to upload data (method PUT). It works normally. However, if I hibernate my computer and power on after 2-3 days (browser still open my website), server response TokenMismatch when I change data. I think that token is expired but I don't know how to resend with valid token without reload page (where I have new token, how to resend data and this token with $resource PUT).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, it seems normal to me that the server returns TokenMIsmatch as it seems normal that the Token used on the front end will be invalid after 2-3 days.

What you can do is automatically reload the page if you receive these specific error (TokenMismatch), for this you can for isntance use : $state.reload();

Comment: I don't want to reload page because it causes flickering and takes time to load old data. Is there any solutions without reloading page? As I know some website such as gmail don't reload whole page when user come back several days.

Comment: Your user has to be identified with a valid Token. If after 2-3 days the Token is not valid, the user has to retrieve a new one.

How does a user has a valid Token in the first place on your website, I guess he has to login ?
If he has to login the first time, when the token is invalid because of time, it means the user has to login again, so you should redirect him to the login page.

If you don't want to do that, I see only two ways: have token that doesn't expire (recommended) or store user credentials in localStorage of the browser (highly insecure)

Comment: I use "remember me" option. If the page is refreshed,  user will have valid token. Therefore, user is not required log in again. But if use javascript (angularjs) to post data (of course not refresh page), server will response token mismatch exception. I am finding the way which don't need to reload page.

Comment: The "remind me" option means that something is stored in cookies or localStorage, so you could use this information to re-login when you got TokenExpire error